# How to get selected file extension from FileChooser in JavaFX2?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2

I realise using Swing and JFileChooser, this is a simple of case of using `getFileFilter` but I can't seem to find any similar options in JavaFX2 for it's FileChooser.

The problem is that when saving a file, if no file extension is explicitly typed by the user, I want the file to be appended with the current selected file extension in the FileChooser drop-down box.

In the image below, I would like this file to be saved as text.xml, for example.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue already reported in jaavfx-jira.You Can trck the status here [unable to save file name with selected extension filter.](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18836)

I am copy pasting info here for quick reference :

> Description : Create a simple program to launch a FileChooser
>   SaveDialog, and add several extension filters, for example: *.txt,
>   *.java, *.*. Run the program, when the save dialog is displayed, select *.txt from the filters, and type file name without extension,
>   then click "Save". Observe the file name to save, the extension ".txt"
>   is not attached, and it seems there is no method of FileChooser to get
>   the selected filter extension. Not sure if it's an expected feature,
>   but it's not convenient.
>
> Type: Feature  Status: Open  Priority: Medium  **Resolution**: **Unresolved**